# How do I create a hardlink in guest user in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, hardlink

Apparently, VirtualBox does allow to create hard and soft links inside guest os on shared folders . Now the thing is I need to install a package that is creating hard links

> Hardlink("lib/abc", "/vagrant/ab/src/.libs/abc")
>   scons: *** [lib/abc] Operation not permitted

I could get symlinks working using this in my vagrant file

> config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]

How can I do the same for hard links?

Comment: How about pointing the install to 'local' disk rather than to a shared folder?  Then move the files afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work for you, but I side-stepped similar problem by creating a samba share from my guest debian VM to my Windows host, and then installing software on the samba share.